# Conditional indexing using solr + rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-solr

So I'm using sunspot-solr in ROR and I need help in creating a searchable block using two tables. 
The query I want to be executed when the indexes are formed is :

```
SELECT a.id,a.title
FROM table_one a,table_two b 
WHERE a.status=1 
AND a.id=b.id 
AND b.status=1
```

Basically,  I want the "title" field to be searchable(text), only if the id exists in both tables and both have status 1.

And I want them to be stored fields(no db hits).

So I did the following :

```
class TableOne

  has_many :table_twos

    searchable do
      text :title, :stored => true
      string :status, :stored => true
      string :id, :multiple => true, :stored => true do
             table_twos.map(&:id)
     end
 end
```

When I use `rake sunspot:reindex`, It is able to load everything from table_one. When it starts indexing with table_two I get the following error:

```
Unknown column 'table_two.table_one_id' in 'where clause'.
```

I think its supposed to be `table_two.id`. How to fix this ?

**UPDATE :**

So, I fixed the issue with

```
has_many :table_tows, foreign_key: "id"
```

Now it looks for `id` in the second table. 
But how do I make only the ones with status=1 to be indexed ???

Comment: If table_one has_many table_twos, then table_two should have an attribute table_one_id to identify the association.  Does it?

Comment: I forgot to mention... I am working on an existing db... not models that I generated with rails...so table_one_id does not exist in table two ... both the tables have columns "id" and I want to match according to that ...